# How to make a C++20 coroutine alternative for this callback situation?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

Assume that we have a well know callback solution that might look like this:
(the code below is pseudocode in C++ syntax because the question is related to C++20 coroutines, necessary boilerplate code is intentionally omitted to make all this more readable)

```
class ICallback
{
public:
  virtual int callbackA(T param1, U param2, V param3)=0;
  virtual int callbackB(int a, double b)=0;
  virtual int callbackC(T1 param1, T2 param2)=0;
};
```

And we have some class that is processing some data and sometimes it calls any of the 3 callback methods:

```
class Processor
{
public:
  explicit Processor(ICallback* callback) : m_callback(callback){} // assume 'callback' cannot be nullptr

  int process(const uint8_t* data, int size)
  {
    int bytes_processed = 0;
    while(bytes_processed != size)
    {
      int bytes_consumed_in_this_iteration = doSomething(data + bytes_processed, size - bytes_processed);
      // Assume that doSomething() might call any callback method through m_callback!!
      bytes_processed += bytes_consumed_in_this_iteration;
    }
    return size; // return value is irrelevant
  }
private:
  int doSomething(const uint8_t* data, int size){ /* assume something useful is going on here */ }
  ICallback* m_callback;
};
```

Just assume that this code above is functional, so we receive calls 'callbackA()', 'callbackB()' and  'callbackC()'.

Now comes the funny part. Coroutines are at this moment a miracle given by gods. They can do everything and more, much more. Allegedly they can replace "callback hell" because they are perfect. So, I tried to do it (and failed). To be honest, coroutines are much bigger hell than all callbacks in the world.

I do understand the entire mambo-jumbo boilerplate code that is required behind things like `T::promise_type` and promise_type's methods like `get_return_object()`, `return_value()` or `return_void()`, `initial_suspend()`, `final_suspend()`, etc... so I won't contaminate with that boilerplate code here. The same applies for our custom `awaiter` object. Therefore, lets jump to the coroutine itself.

```
SomeType startCoroutine(/* don't really know what to put here*/)
{
  // First, I don't know how to feed a coroutine with data. What if I receive data over a socket?
  // I don't expect anyone to write the actual code, a comment and pseudocode with the most crucial parts should do
  
  // even if we ignore that hard part of delivering input data to the coroutine and simply assume that it's here even though we don't know how it arrived, what's next?

  byte data[100]; // assume it contains valid payload
  
  co_await std::make_pair(data, sizeof(data)); // calls promise_type::await_transform(std::pair<const uint8_t*, const uint32_t> value), it creates an instance of 'awaiter' and calls awaiter::await_ready() and then awaiter::await_resume() or awaiter::await_suspend(), depending on the awaiter::await_ready's() return value.

  // so, if we implement in our awaiter::await_resume() or in awaiter::await_suspend() something like Processor::process() from the beginning, but without callbacks, what should be done if after processing first 2 bytes we detect that now is the time to return control to the caller in the coroutine because we don't use callbacks any more? It can be done via await_resume(), but that returns the result, so we cannot go back and process the remaining 98 bytes of our data. If we remain in the suspended state, what then? We can resume, but resuming will call await_resume() again.
}
```

Comment: "*Coroutines are at this moment a miracle given by gods. They can do everything and more, much more. Allegedly they can replace "callback hell" because they are perfect.*" That's not remotely true. Coroutines have their uses, but those uses have nothing to do with "callback hell" (whatever that is). A coroutine is about pausing a function's execution and scheduling its resumption with some other object. While that can be used in a callback-based API (the callback resumes the coroutine), that has no relation to what your code seems to be trying to do here.

Comment: I could imagine that `process` could be a coroutine generator, where each invocation returns a byte range of some sort and the caller processes the returned byte range. However, the fact that the byte range being processed is determined by this `doSomething` function which calls into user-provided code makes this non-workable. Or at least, not easily.

Comment: Where are you trying to put the coroutine? Are you writing an instance of `ICallback`, or are you replacing `Processor`?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, well, I based my ironic comments on many articles/videos where authors claimed how using callback is a nightmare (although I cannot see that nightmare) and how coroutines are much better because they offer "better" way for the same functionality. Based on your comment, it seems that coroutines should be used with additional threads, so that scheduled execution is being done by some other thread(s). Right?

Comment: @Caleth, the idea of this experiment was to replace `Processor` with something else that uses coroutines. Of course, the new solution would not use `ICallback` either.

Comment: @fyou: "*authors claimed how using callback is a nightmare*" I did some searching for "callback hell" and I only found such statements referring to deep, nested sequences of callbacks. None of them are saying that using a callback is hell. And you're not even really using a "callaback"; it's just a virtual function call.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, the user provides an object derived from `ICallback`, so it is the same as having a method (or three of them) that accepts a pure function pointer. In both cases calls go into user provided code.

Comment: @fyou: In terms of function, yes; you can see a base class as just a bunch of function pointers. But in terms of the conceptual idea of a callback? No; the bundle of functions within a class *mean something*. They're not arbitrary; they are grouped together because they have logical meaning and interconnectedness. A base class is not *just* a callback.

Comment: Yes, the conceptual idea is exactly calling back, hence callback. Grouped inside a class or not, interconnected or not, it's still a CALLBACK, whether you like it or not. Calling back is exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

First define some types holding the same data passed to the callbacks:

```
struct EventA { T param1; U param2; V param3; };
struct EventB { int a; double b };
struct EventC { T1 param1; T2 param2; };

using Event = std::variant<EventA, EventB, EventC>;
```

Now we change `Processor::process` into a free-function coroutine, perhaps with helper functions.

```
std::generator<Event> process(const uint8_t* data, int size)
{
  int bytes_processed = 0;
  while(bytes_processed != size)
  {
    auto [bytes_consumed_in_this_iteration, event] = doSomething(data + bytes_processed, size - bytes_processed);
    if (event)
      co_yield *event;
    bytes_processed += bytes_consumed_in_this_iteration;
  }
}

std::tuple<int, std::optional<Event>> doSomething(const uint8_t* data, int size) // stuff here, maybe creates an Event
```

Now this does require a type that's only in C++23, [`std::generator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/generator), but that is a widely applicable library type, you aren't fiddling around with defining a specific promise type yourself

I'm not sure this matches the call pattern that your `doSomething` has for the callbacks in `ICallback`, I'm assuming at most one callback per invocation of `doSomething`. If there are more, you'd need to return a range of `Event`s, and then it'd be `co_yield std::ranges::elements_of(events)`.